# How to keep list items after a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, webforms

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms in C#

I have a GridView with a list of available rooms, each with a 'Reserve' button in a column next to each of them. When 'Reserve' is clicked, i want an object of the Room class, selectedRoom, to be made that contains the same information that was present as when it was in the availableRooms list.

The availableRooms list is initialised outside of any of these methods, in the WebForms method.

Here is a snippet of my BtnSearch_Click method, which actually does successfully display the GridView on the page:

```
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Room room = new Room();
                room.roomID = reader.GetInt32("roomID");
                room.roomName = reader.GetString("roomName");
                room.roomType = reader.GetString("typeName");
                room.enSuite = reader.GetBoolean("enSuite");
                room.ppNight = reader.GetFloat("pricePerNight");

                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ppAddAdult")))
                {
                    room.ppAddAdult = reader.GetFloat("ppAddAdult");
                }
                else
                {
                    room.ppAddAdult = 0.0f;
                    //allows null value
                }

                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ppAddChild")))
                {
                    room.ppAddChild = reader.GetFloat("ppAddChild");
                }
                else
                {
                    room.ppAddChild = 0.0f;
                    //allows null values
                }
                
                TimeSpan lengthStay = checkOutDate - checkInDate;
                //calculate length of stay
                room.lengthStay = (int)lengthStay.TotalDays;
                room.price = room.GetPrice(Convert.ToInt32(adultGuests.Text), Convert.ToInt32(childGuests.Text));
                //calculate price
                availableRooms.Add(room);
                //add current room to list
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = Convert.ToString(ex);
    }
}
gridViewRooms.DataSource = availableRooms;
gridViewRooms.DataBind();
//provide data source and bind data for gridView
```

And here is a snippet of my reserve button logic:

```
 protected void gridViewRooms_reserveCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.CommandName == "Reserve")
     {
         using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             try
             {
                 connection.Open();
                 int accountID = 0;
                 DateTime checkOutDate = Convert.ToDateTime(checkOut.Text);
                 DateTime checkInDate = Convert.ToDateTime(checkIn.Text);
                 //initalise variables

                 int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                 Room selectedRoom = availableRooms.Find(room => room.roomID == rowID);
                 //define the currently selected room
```

The thing that confuses me is that the availableRooms list displays perfectly on the page, but suddenly is empty when I click 'Reserve', preventing selectedRoom being made.

I have tried repopulating the availableRooms list by calling the BtnSearch_Click method again but it produced many, many errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am very new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother using the command "system" built into the GridView (they are messy, and don't help much -- really, they don't!!!).

However, either way (a standard plain jane button and button click), or the use of command of the GridView)?

You need to get the given clicked row, and then you MUST use find.control to get/pull/see/use the control(s) for that given GridView row.

So, you need the current GridViewRow. You then use .FindControl method.

It's not clear why/how your posted code compiles, but the use of

```
room.roomID
```

That is a valid control on the GridView (I assume), but those templated controls in the GridView have many and multiple instances of those controls for each row.

So, you have to pull the room.id value (control) for the CURRENT row.

(or better in your case pull the combo box control).

In fact, for things like a primary key value (database PK), I don't suggest including the PK values in the GridView markup (it's a big security risk, and you can use data keys for that purpose). This means you don't have to include the database PK column value in your GridView markup.

Ok, so you have to get the current row here first.

Then get/grab the instance of the given control for that one row of the GridView.

If the user changes/selects a room type, if you not saved it back to the database, then your code to find/get/use the room type by database "room type id" not going to work unless you save the data row back to the database each time a user changes the room type.

Now, if such a room change with that combo ALWAYS forces an update to the database, then your find code for room type should work.

However, if the user can freely change the room type combo and you don't save back to the database?

Then as noted, the value(s) for the current GridView row should be used.

So, to pull/get the values from the current row, then:

Button markup in grid can be this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Row Click"
                            CommandName="RowClick"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And row command can be this:

```
    protected void GVHotels_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "RowClick")
        {
            Button btn = (Button)e.CommandSource;
            GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

            Debug.Print($"Row index = {gRow.RowIndex}");
            int PK = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
            Debug.Print($"Database PK = {PK}");

            CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");

            Debug.Print($"Check box setting = {chkSel.Checked}");
        }
    }
```

So, in my case, I had/have a check box on the current row.

e.g. this:

[image]

So, my check box on that row was this:

```
    <asp:TemplateField 
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" 
                OnCheckedChanged="chkSel_CheckedChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And as noted, we don't have to use "command" here, but just a simple button.

So, in your markup, using a button like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdRowBtn" runat="server" Text="Row Click"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
            OnClick="cmdRowBtn_Click"
            />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then our button code becomes this:

```
    protected void cmdRowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        Debug.Print($"Row index = {gRow.RowIndex}");
        int PK = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
        Debug.Print($"Database PK = {PK}");

        CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");

        Debug.Print($"Check box setting = {chkSel.Checked}");

    }
```

You can still use "CommandArgs" in above if you wish.

So, any standard event for the given control can be used. You thus can then pick up current row with "Naming Container". This works for click events, even a dropdown selected index change event or whatever.

As above 2 examples show, once we get our hands on the current GridViewRow, then we have to use the .FindControl() method of that given row.

For non templated columns, you use the .cells[] collection of the GridViewRow and for templated columns, then you have to use .FindControl. I think in your case you want RoomType. (But not sure what that control is in the GridView. I suppose you can "walk back to the database based on PK assuming that combo ALWAYS updates the database. If not, then you need to pull from the GridView and not the database as you are.

So, in your case, get current row, and then use .FindControl() method to the get the given control, of which then you are free to use/get the .text value of that desired control, or even the selected index or whatever.

edit:

I should also note for some reason your code stub is not a row command. As noted, just wire up a standard button you place in the GridView, and then use the code to get the current grid row. From that you can pull the current selected index of the dropdown list, or the DataText field, or the DataValue field of that combo. So, with both the row "room.id" and the room type, you should be able to pull the data in any fashion you wish.

## Edit: Putting Above into practice.

Ok, so assume this GridView markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
    OnRowDataBound="GVHotels_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Room Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoomType" runat="server"
                    DataValueField="ID"
                    DataTextField="RoomType"
                    Width="180px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdRowBtn" runat="server" Text="Row Click"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                    OnClick="cmdRowBtn_Click"
                    CssClass="btn" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code to load the GridView:

```
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    DataTable rstRoomTypes = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
            Session["rstData"] = rstData;
        }
        else
            rstData = (DataTable)Session["rstData"];
            
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        rstRoomTypes =  // Load combo choices
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM vRoomTypes ORDER BY ID");

        rstData = General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GVHotels.DataSource = rstData;
        GVHotels.DataBind();
    }


    protected void GVHotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlRoomType = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlRoomType");

            ddlRoomType.DataSource = rstRoomTypes;
            ddlRoomType.DataBind();
            ddlRoomType.Items.Insert(0, "Select RoomType");
            // setup current cbo setting for this row of data.
            DataRowView RowData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (RowData["RoomType"].ToString() != "")
                ddlRoomType.Text = RowData["RoomType"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

Note the use of row data bind to setup each row with the ddl.

And now our row click code is this:

```
    protected void cmdRowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData(); // optional save data

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int PK = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        DropDownList ddlRoomType = (DropDownList)gRow.FindControl("ddlRoomType");

        string sInfo =
            $@"Row index click = {gRow.RowIndex} <br/>
            RoomType = {ddlRoomType.SelectedItem.Value} - {ddlRoomType.SelectedItem.Text} <br/>
            Database PK (Hotel) = {PK}";
        lblInfo.Text = sInfo;
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, note the button click for the row click. The event stub is standard, and we pick up the current row information by using of naming container.

The other HUGE tip here? Don't use sqlDatasource(s) in the markup, since then you can't control WHEN they re-load. In other words, place your data load code in the !IsPostBack stub in the page load event. Thus, you now will not experience re-binding and re-loading of data on the page, and if a sqlDataSouce on a page "decides" to re-load a control, then your lose your current selection of that control.

So, note how in my 2nd example, I load up a combo box for each grid row, but they can well survive post backs since I avoided using sqlDataSource objects in the markup. SqlDataSource(s) in the markup are a great and quick solution, but the instant your code on the page becomes complex, then that's the first thing I recommend you dump and avoid (since you lose control as to when such data sources are triggered for re-loading such controls, and you don't want that occurring unless you the developer says so by use of your code behind).